# Java Debug Wire Protocol Remote Code Execution Vulnerability - joss

Tags: tcp, jboss, jboss7.x, jdwp

Our security team found below issue with JDWP in jboss. **How can I fix this ?**

> -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=changeit -Dhttps.protocols=TLSv1 -Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,address=8787,server=y,suspend=n -Dsun.rmi.dgc.client.gcInterval=3600000 -Dsun.rmi.dgc.server.gcInterval=3600000 -Dorg.jboss.boot.log.file=/

**Title**: Java Debug Wire Protocol Remote Code Execution Vulnerability

### Severity: Critical

## Description

#### Affected Hosts

- IP address:tcp/8787

The remote server is running Java Debug Wire Protocol service. No authentication is required if the service is enabled.

The vulnerabilities can be exploited by malicious users to execute arbitrary code.

## Remediation

Disable the service

## Proof of Concept

Java Debug Wire Protocol Remote Code Execution Vulnerability detected on port 8787 over TCP.

Thanks,
Vishnu

Comment: Did you get any solution? I also need to fix this Vulnerability

Answer (score 1):

You just need to disable the remote debugging. Change your command options to:

```
-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=changeit -Dhttps.protocols=TLSv1 -Dsun.rmi.dgc.client.gcInterval=3600000 -Dsun.rmi.dgc.server.gcInterval=3600000 -Dorg.jboss.boot.log.file=/
```

Answer (score 1):

You have: `address=8787` (in my case, I had `address=*:5005`) which means your machine will accept connections from any host ([source](http://www.jbixbe.com/doc/tutorial/RemoteDebugging.html)). This allows an attacker to execute arbitrary code on the machine running this (yet another [source](https://www.acunetix.com/vulnerabilities/web/java-debug-wire-protocol-remote-code-execution/)).
In my case disabling remote debug wasn't an option, so instead I specified which hosts can have access, which was the localhost, i.e., `address=localhost:5005`. This allows only the localhost to connect and no one else.